# Can not we initialize a Font for second time in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, fonts, reference, initialization, drawing

I am making a *2D game* in *VB.NET*. I use only one font object to draw strings on the form. This font is only needed in *Game Menu*. Therefore I dispose the font when it is not necessary and initialize it again when needed.

> font_1 = New Font("Autobus Bold", 15.0)

When I use this font (font_1) to draw a string on the form, I get this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

When I view the the font, it shows,

> {Name = Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
>   Size=15.0}

This error doesn't happen when the game menu is loaded for the first time (when *font_1* is initialized for the first time). When the user plays the game, font is disposed. When user enters to *Game Menu* again, font is initialized again before it is used for drawing. When font is used for drawing a string on the window, this error happens.

It looks like error is only within the Font Family. I saw this question in few forums, but no one had given a solution. (This is my first question in a forum)

Edited : I removed the Font(font_1). But still I get the same error. Here is the code that draws the string.

> ```
> Private Sub mcFramesHandler_TIMER_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mcFramesHandler_TIMER.Tick
>
>     gB.Clear(Color.Black)
>     gB.DrawImage(Background_IMG, 0, 0, 640, 480)
>
>     Select Case currentMode
>
>         Case GameMode.OnGame
>             If mcShoot_TIMER.Enabled Then gB.DrawImage(Bullet_IMG, Bullet_X, Bullet_Y, 20, 50)
>             If mcEneShoot_TIMER.Enabled Then gB.DrawImage(EneBullet_IMG, EneBullet_X, EneBullet_Y, 20, 50)
>             If Shooter_Lives Then gB.DrawImage(Shooter_IMG, Shooter_X, Bullet_Y_Def, 100, 105)
>             If mcMoveEnemy_TIMER.Enabled Then gB.DrawImage(Enemy_IMG, Enemy_X, 10, 100, 80)
>             If mcExplode_TMER.Enabled Then gB.DrawImage(Explotion_IMG, Explotion_X, Explotion_Y, 100, 80)
>
>         Case GameMode.Begining
>             gB.DrawString("Start", New Font("Autobus Bold", 15.0), textBrush(0), 110, 98) 'Error is generated in this line
>             gB.DrawString("Credits", New Font("Autobus Bold", 15.0), textBrush(1), 102, 158)
>             gB.DrawString("Exit", New Font("Autobus Bold", 15.0), textBrush(2), 114, 218)
>
>     End Select
>
>     Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(backbuffer, 0, 0, 640, 480)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Here textBrudh(0) is a brush. gB is the Graphic object. gB successfully draws the background image before it draws the string. This happens only when *Game Menu* is displayed
Your support is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're initializing a different instance of a Font object or you're trying to set a value/argument with a source value that can only accessed through an existing reference. You should post the code that geneates the exception and the code that initializes the original instance of the Font. Anyway, since you have a Font object that use more than once, you could simply keep it and dispose of if when the application terminates.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check it again. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes, well, as already mentioned, you need to post the code that initializes the Font and the method where the exception is raised. A single line of code doesn't say much about the state of these objects.

Comment: I edited it again. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Thee roots of the problems you have run deeper than you think. What you should try is to eliminate this: `Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(backbuffer, 0, 0, 640, 480)`. In WinForms, the `Paint` event of controls (Forms included) is used for drawing. The `PaintEventArgs`'s `e.Graphics` object provides the tools for drawing in that specific device context. You should re-design keeping this in mind. Many, many examples around. A lot of *strange* things go away when you have made these changes.

Comment: I used the paint event before. Then I figured out this way. Then I calculated the time difference for these 2 options. I saw that, drawing to PaintEventArg is slower. Can you suggest me a method to refresh the form. I used a timer for that which had a interval of 20 milliseconds. Thank you again.

Comment: There's no possible way that drawing in the Paint event is slower than anything else that uses `Control.CreateGraphics`. The graphics object is created anyway, that you use it or not, so you're, among other things, creating it twice, it's non-persistent thus it cannot be stored etc.. -- A [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer)'s resolution is min ~55ms.

Comment: Anyway for that, form should be refreshed every time using a timer. This method directly draws to the form within one function. Since you are continuously suggest this method, I will use Paint event to draw from now.

Comment: If you need to refresh a Form's graphics with a Timer, in the Timer's `Tick` event call `Me.Invalidate()`. It will raise the `Paint` event, where all drawings are perfomed. That's all. Activating the `DoubleBuffered` feature may help to speed up the process a bit. Or a lot, it depends on what/how you're drawing.

Comment: Yeah. I used that method before. But instead of invalidate I used refresh and set double buffer in on load event. Thanks anyway. I didn't know invalidate unables double buffer.

Comment: `Invalidate()` does not activate double buffering. It's used to raise the `Paint` event only. It doesn't do anything else. The buffered graphics feature can be enabled setting `Control.DoubleBuffered = true;`, where available. Otherwise with `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` in a Form's or a custom controls' constructor. PictureBox and Label (when `FlatStyle` is not `System`) controls have it enabled by default.

Comment: So what's the difference between Refresh and Invalidate

Comment: You can see it clearly in the .Net Source Code: [Control.Refresh()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,11107) calls `Control.Invalidate(true)` (meaning, post a message to redraw the entire window) and `Control.Update()` (which calls the native `UpdateWindow` method, meaning *do it now*). So Invalidate() is asynchronous (enqueues the `WM_PAINT` message), `Refresh()` causes the same message to be processed ASAP. In normal conditions, you call `Invalidate()`, in a closer loop, you may choose `Refresh()`.

Comment: That's lot of information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the brush (textBrush : an array of brush). When I dsipose each item in the array and re initialize, looks like something has happened to them (like they are not brushes anymore. See the error again. It says "Parameter is not valid"). So I just redim the array to 0.

```
Redim textBrush (0)
```

This clears previous items. Then I redim the array again initilizes each of them when needed.

```
Redim textBrush (2)
textBrush (0) = Brushes.Yellow
textBrush (1) = Brushes.Red
textBrush (2) = Brushes.Red
```

This array is used to change text color when up  and down key is pressed.
I saw lot of people had mentioned this error in forums

> {Name = Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. Size=15.0}

I don't what this name is, but it doesn't effect the programme. It is always like that in any Font.

Answer (score 0):

After you have finished to draw your things you need to dispose all objects around Graphics, not only the font but all (better with closure techniques like code below)

If you need a new instace of Graphics you can create this at the moment this is needed without using a Global object (when you work with Graphics).

```
     Using gB As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

        Using textBrush As Brush = Brushes.Black

            Using font_1 As Font = New Font("Courier New", 15)

                gB.DrawString("Start", font_1, textBrush, 400, 98)

                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()
                'gB.DrawOtherthings()

            End Using

        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: Isn't this making game slower. This timer has an interval of 20 milliseconds. I dispose all the images when game is changing from menu to playing mode and vice versa. But I don't dispose graphic object and the backbuffer(background) since these two are always used (in playing mode and in the game menu). Please make me correct if I am wrong. I love to know things and speedup the game. It lags sometimes.

Comment: Why at a certain point you dont'use again gB?? but Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(backbuffer, 0, 0, 640, 480)

Comment: Another thing is, avoid to draw things which doesn't change every 20 ms. Doesn't make sense

Comment: Try to re-draw this things when is fired an certain event you know that something change

Comment: I have to clear the backbuffer to make a simple change. When it is cleared, it should be drawn again. I guess that's how 3D games work too. The whole image is drawn in every frame. I appreciate your comments. I want to know more.

Comment: But i tried your code too. Still it gives the same issue. And I figure out problem is not with the font at all. {Name = Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. Size=15.0} is always same.

Comment: Where gB is come from?? Do the Owner is disposed? Put a Try block and write in console if catch an error on timer.tick there

Comment: I posted an answer. gB means graphics for backbuffer. It draws several images on a specific Image (backbuffer) and finally present it on the form's client area.

Comment: I'm glad you have figure out - We hadn't seen all the code :( . However in the first question seems you are drawing the same objects every 20ms. If I'm i your shoes I avoid that.Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's the procedure. Now I'm gonna change it to a loop. It will continously draw without a specific time interval :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.At this point I think is better with a interval (like you actually can) than a cycle “For”. In an interval the processor/thread have more time than a cycle “For,” that means make processor/thread more busy.
My topic was another: Don’t draw the same things while those doesn’t change. :)

Comment: Welcome, But i have to clear the surface draw any thing. So finally, i have to draw everything from the beginning. And I will keep using timer event to draw.